# How do I use an If-Else query based on the day of the week?

Tags: shell, shell-script, date, test

Problem: I need to check if today is Thursday and perform different actions based on the result of this condition. I tried two different approaches:

#### Getting the Day Name:

```
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%a")
echo DAYOFWEEK: $DAYOFWEEK
if ["$DAYOFWEEK" == "Thu"]; 
then   
   echo YES
else
    echo NO
fi
```

#### Getting the Day Num:

```
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%u")
echo DAYOFWEEK: $DAYOFWEEK

if ["$DAYOFWEEK" == 4]; 
then
   echo YES
else
   echo NO
fi
```

In both cases, the output is NO, even though it should be YES. What is wrong?

Comment: A side note: those `;` would be required if you would have `then` in the same line with `if`. In this case they are redundant.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem is the missing blank.

The following code will work in shells whose `[` builtin command accepts `==` as an alias for `=`:

```
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 4 ];  then    echo YES; else    echo NO; fi
```

But keep in mind (see `help test` in `bash`):

- `==` is not officially mentioned, you should use `=` for string compare
- `-eq` is intended for decimal arithmetic tests (won't make a difference here for `date +%u` but would for `date +%d` for instance when it comes to comparing `04` and `4` which are numerically the same but lexically different).

I would prefer:

```
 if [ "${DAYOFWEEK}" -eq 4 ];  then    echo YES; else    echo NO; fi
```

Generally you should prefer the day *number* approach, because it has less dependency to the current *locale*. 
On my system the output of `date +"%a"` is today `Do`.

Answer (score 5):

Don't overlook `case` which is often a better way to do this kind of things:

Also beware that the output of `date +%a` is locale-dependent, so if you expect the English names, your script will stop working when invoked by a French or Korean user for instance.

```
case $(LC_ALL=C date +%a) in
   (Mon) echo first day of the week;;
   (Thu) do-something;;
   (Sat|Sun) echo week-end;;
   (*) echo any other day;; # last ;; not necessary but doesn't harm
esac
```

Note that above is one of the rare cases where that  `$(...)` doesn't need to be quoted (though quotes won't harm. Same as in `var="$(...)"`).

Comment: `case` is my best bash friend.

Answer (score 0):

In the same idea, I use the following piece of code to "disable" a cron before a chosen hour

*Of course, I would rather modify the crontab itself... if I were granted the necessary rights to :)*

Here's a simple test which aborts a bash script unless we're at night.

```
# Delay or restrict execution.
# Here, we quit unless hour is greater than (gt) 2 and (-a) lower than (lt) 7
# i.e. execution happens only at 3,4,5&6 o'clock.
if  /usr/bin/test `date '+%H'` -gt 2 -a `date '+%H'` -lt 7; then
  echo LETS_START_PROCESSING;
else
  exit;
fi

#Put job here
```

Comment: Why use `/usr/bin/test` instead of the shell's builtin `[` command?

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas I didn't use 3,4,5,6 because I don't have access to the crontab.  (*this is the 2nd line of my post* :)
Our servers are managed by Claranet, and we already lost a week of ticket-ping-pong to get... a working cron (not kidding).  So we avoid messing up and re-opening tickets when we can :)
For that reason, we asked for an hourly cron task instead of daily, and until all our tests are done, it will be way easier not to touch the task, and add our controls in the executed script.

Comment: Ah OK, sorry, I thought you meant you didn't have the right to modify the `cron` executable as opposed to the user's crontab.

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas 
About the test syntax, I preferred it over [] or [[]] because I tried my script on some other server first, where I *could* use the crontab. After too many surprises with crons, I got the habit to use absolute path in crontabs as much as possible.  One may say it makes tests ugly, and will be right... but I'll answer that shell test are **always** ugly anyway, and will be right too ^^
What matters to me was mostly to have an answer which would work with a simple copy/paste, and include some explainations.

Comment: Note that `-a` is deprecated in `test`. Standardly, you'd use: `hour=$(date +%H); if [ "$hour" -gt 2 ] && [ "$hour" -lt 7 ]` (or `hour=\`date +%H\`` if you needed to be compatible to the Bourne shell, that is Solaris 10 and older and maybe some rare SCO unices nowadays)

Answer (score 0):

To stop the script in day of week, only delete the line of the day:

```
DAYOFWEEK=$(date +"%u")
echo "$DAYOFWEEK";
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 1 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 2 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 3 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 4 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 5 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 6 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" == 7 ]; then exit; else echo; fi
```

Comment: Welcome on the Unix SE! I am not sure if I understood your first line correctly. Wouldn't be an `if [ "$DAYOFWEEK" -lt 7 ]` better?

Answer (score -2):

Firstly you should quote the assignment
DAYOFWEEK="$(date +%u)"

And you need to have spaces on each side of the [ and ] brackets.

The semi-colon at the end of the line is redundant.

Comment: The quoting is not needed.

Comment: To expand on @H.-DirkSchmitt's comment: the *reason* why the quoting is not needed is that the output will not contain any spaces.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling: No - it is never needed ;-)

Try the example: `a=$(echo 1 2 3); echo $a;`

Comment: @H.-DirkSchmitt `a=$(echo "1 2 3"); echo $a` with multiple spaces between the digits (StackExchange won't let me make it a simple copy-and-paste, unfortunately).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling - see man bash 
"If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and pathname expansion are not performed on the results." So it makes in the case of the question and the "1 2 3" example no difference.

Comment: No, Bash do not require it, but you open yourself up to many potential problems, including portability.  I am willing to re-phrase my answer to read "should" in stead of must to satisfy the purists.

Comment: @user, in `a=$(echo '1   2 3'); echo "$a"`, the quotes are required around `$a` to prevent IFS-split+glob (where space is only special in that it's in the default value of `$IFS`), it's not needed around `$(...)` here, not because of what characters that expansion contains (even if there are `$IFS` or glob character) but because it's used in the value of a scalar assignment, so that can yield only word value, so splitting or globbing wouldn't make sense. You'd need the quotes if assigning to an array like with `a=( "$(...)" )`