# How can I collapse three statements into one?

Tags: shell-script

I need to create an .sh script, which is a new thing for me. I have some examples to follow but I'm hoping to do better.

I see something like this:

```
date -d $date | grep "Fri"
$status=$?
if [ ${status} == 0 ]; then
```

Is it possible to collapse this snippet into a single line to this effect?

```
if [ date -d $date | grep "Fri" = 0 ]; then
```

I removed the double '=', as I understand it is redundant.

Comment: You can do better. see [How do I use an If-Else query based on the day of the week?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/67184/how-do-i-use-an-if-else-query-based-on-the-day-of-the-week)

Comment: @αғsнιη that answers the side-effect of the question but not the question being asked, which is how to test the result of a command directly without needing to use `$?`

Comment: correct. but still that answer shows how to do it correctly for thier needs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply test the exit status of the last command in the pipeline directly,

```
if date -d "$date" | grep -F "Fri"
then
    …
fi
```

I've double-quoted the variable `$date` to protect it from inadvertent split/glob actions by the shell. And I've used `grep -F` for a direct string match without Regular Expressions.

However, you could also write this particular example directly in a locale-independent manner without needing `grep` at all, by asking `date` to tell you the day of the week:

```
if [ "$(date -d "$date" +'%w')" -eq 5 ]
then
    …
fi
```